# Questions About Drawing without WM_PAINT Message

Tags: windows, drawing, message, gdi

In MSDN, I read this

> When drawing without using a WM_PAINT message, the application usually
>   does not invalidate the window. Instead, it draws in such a fashion
>   that it can easily restore the window and remove the drawing.

What does it means ? Becuase I wrote a GIS program, I want to implement the "Zoom In" feature,
Mouse left button down and move the mouse to draw a rectangle, it's drawing a rectangle but the rectangle cover the map, first I think it is becuase the rectangle is not transparent, then I use AlphaBlend() to draw a transparent rectangle, it is the same.
What should I do ?

[image: draw a rectangle]

```
LRESULT OnMouseMove(UINT nflags, CPoint point)
{
    if (m_bZoomInMode)
    {
        m_curScreenPoint.x = point.x;
        m_curScreenPoint.y = point.y;
        HDC hdc = GetDC();
        SelectObject(hdc, (HBRUSH)NULL_BRUSH);
        Rectangle(hdc, m_startScreenPoint.x, m_startScreenPoint.y, point.x, point.y);
        ReleaseDC(hdc);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The comment in MSDN is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: The trick to drawing a selection rectangle is to set the drawing pen to XOR mode `SetROP2(hDC, R2_XORPEN);` and with a hollow brush. The first draw will draw a line-rectangle which invert the original screen pixels, second draw on the same rectangle will restore the original pixels. Refer to this example: http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/windows/104684/104684/drawing-a-selection-box-on-screen-with-the-mouse---example-code/

Comment: If you are using MFC in your project, you can simply use the `CRectTracker` class.

Answer (score 1):

To draw the rectangle, you can draw 4 lines. Or use a clear brush – that is use brush style `BS_HOLLOW`.

The other issue to solve is that as the user moves the mouse and the zoom rectangle will move and you will need to repaint what lies underneath. Do this as follows:

1. Call `InvalidateRect` passing a rect for the previous location of the zoom rectangle.
2. Call `UpdateRect` for force a paint cycle and paint what was under the previous zoom rectangle.
3. Draw the new zoom rectangle.